# Orbeon 2018.1 bug in initialization of opsXFormsProperties

Tags: orbeon

I've loaded a vanilla install of the Orbeon 2018.1 in Tomcat 9.0.11. The main /home/ page works, but when I click to Form Runner (http://localhost:8080/orbeon2018/fr/)

I get this in the browser console and the page doesn't load:

[image: Safari inspector]

The (main) issue turns out to be a malformed line here, generated by ScriptBuilder.scala

`var opsXFormsProperties = {, "session-heartbeat-delay": 34560000 "format.input.time": "[h]:[m]:[s] [P,*-2]", "retry.delay-increment": 5000, "retry.max-delay": 30000, "delay-before-ajax-timeout": 30000
};`

Note the leading comma before `"session-heartbeat-delay": 34560000` that should have come right after that fragment.

Comment: Looking at the code, I don't understand how this is possible. The comma appears before instead of after the property name/value.

Comment: The code puts a comma before outputting any property except at index 0. I can only see how there could be a leading comma if at index 0, the property at index 0 is not written.

Comment: Exactly. And it always at least outputs some `"` and you would expect that if the property value was null you would see `null`. That's why it doesn't make sense to me!

Comment: Nonetheless I've been testing for two/three days straight and this thing keeps coming back as I update my form in eXist-db and refresh the browser page. So far what works: go back to vanilla Orbeon, load Form Runner page once, throw in all our updates. If I don't run the form runner page once, the problem stays. It must be a cache thing, but where....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news: we have identified this issue. See [#3736](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3736). We will have to produce a 2018.1.1 release with this fix.